# How to add "Forthcoming" to year bibliography field in pandoc/pandoc-citeproc

Tags: bibtex, pandoc-citeproc

I'm trying to cite a paper that is forthcoming, and unfortunately if I put `year = {Forthcoming}` in my BibTeX citation entry, pandoc-citeproc always takes this as `n.d.` (e.g. "Greig (n.d.)" in footnotes/bibliography entry). Ideally it'd be nice to have it just output `Forthcoming` (e.g. "Greig (Forthcoming").

I tried searching here and other places for solutions to this issue, but couldn't find anything. I then tried using some suggested solutions from others with a standard LaTeX/BibTeX output---e.g. here: https://jblevins.org/log/forthcoming.

I attempted this (from the link above):

```latex
@Preamble{ " \newcommand{\noop}[1]{} " }

@Article{smith-2011,
  author  = "John Smith", 
  year    = 2011,
  journal = "Unorganized Scholarly Impressions",
  ...
}

@Article{smith-inpress-a,
  author  = "John Smith", 
  year    = "\noop{3001}in press",
  journal = "Journal of Nothingness",
  ...
}

@Article{smith-inpress-b,
   author  = "John Smith", 
   year    = "\noop{3002}forthcoming",
   journal = "Review of Random Thoughts",
   ...
}
```

Unfortunately pandoc-citeproc doesn't seem to do anything with `\noop{xxx}forthcoming`---I still get `n.d.` in the resulting citation. I would otherwise expect `Forthcoming` (e.g. "Greig (Forthcoming) ...").

How would I then go about that when exporting citations via pandoc/pandoc-citeproc?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked out totally how to implement this myself, but for "forthcoming" works, the variable you'll want to use is "status" and not "year". You can look at this closed issue from JGM to see a bit about usage [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/issues/57).

Comment: Please include a short excerpt of the code in case the issue goes missing at some point (ability to fully remove your own issues was added last year)